# Do letters from the NSF to professors have to be discarded with extra care?

Tags: nsf

I recently saw some NSF letters left in a box with some books, and the box was left to the side of a trash bin, in case people wanted those books. I looked through the books and also saw the NSF letters, which were basically messages sent from some NSF director to the professor, urging everyone to participate in some big change in the review process.  It doesn't seem like anything Top Secret but I am curious to know:

Do such NSF letters have to be discarded with extra care?  Should I have notified this professor that he shouldn't leave such letters in plain view of students?

Comment: Why would they need such consideration?

Comment: If it needed special consideration it would be marked as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems unlikely for most mail. There might be exceptions, but the recipient would be expected to know when it is important. However, most of the mail that a person might consider important to destroy securely would also likely be the mail that they would retain in a file.

It isn't the NSA, of course.

Comment: The NSA is smart enough (or paranoid enough) never to send anything that is important enough to need secure destruction through the mail.